# Timezone set in .user.ini file doesn't apply

Tags: php, timezone, azure-web-app-service

I have a PHP Web App running in Azure and I want to change the default timezone from UTC to Europe\London. I've added `date.timezone=Europe/London` to the `.user.ini` as instructed by Microsoft documentation.

The change appears if I run `phpinfo();` (see picture). However, if I run `var_dump(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));` the date is returned as: `string(19) "25/06/2020 17:34:14"` which is incorrect, it's the UTC time.

Also, if I run `date_default_timezone_get()`, UTC is returned. It's driving me insane.

I would grateful if anyone could point me to what I'm missing. Thank you.

[image]

Update:

I had a look at the php.ini file and the timezone seems to be overwritten by the [WebPIChanges] section at the end of the file. The problem is, I cannot edit the php.ini file in Azure. Do you know of any way of removing this section from it?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: I've followed the exact same steps in Azure and I'm still getting the UTC date, one hour behind London. Have you seen the update I added? Do you have this tag?

Answer (score 0):

It just works as expected on my side. See my detailed steps as below.

1.Create a `.user.ini` file under **wwwroot** folder.

[image]

2.Add `date.timezone=Europe/London` to it.

[image]

3.Restart your webapp

[image]

4.Check the result

```
<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();
var_dump(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
phpinfo();
```

[image]